# What's the terminal velocity of an object accelerated by a constant force in interstellar space

Tags: relativity, kinetic-theory

Terminal Velocity is the velocity at which a the gravitational acceleration and the drag of the air cancel each other out to zero change in velocity. While one might think that space as a vacuum, it really isn't. The [interstellar medium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium) has densities between 10^-4 and 10^6 molecules per cube centimetre. Assuming an indestructible object is accelerated constantly with a force of $F$, what will be its terminal velocity? The relativistic effects evolved in this make this above my pay grade. An optimal answer would provide me with a formula for the terminal velocity depending on the objects acceleration.

Comment: You need to give more details. Terminal velocity requires to know the shape and the surface finish of the object.

Comment: @SV Let's assume that it is shaped so that it helps to optimise the terminal velocity. This means it is spherical, like a hyipersonic projectile, right? Surface finish?

Comment: if the object is always accelerating then it will not reach a terminal velocity, other than getting asymptotically close to c, the speed of light

Comment: Also, if it is acceleration can't be constant, because then there is no terminal velocity. Maybe you mean constant force

Comment: @DyingOfLight is it smooth or rough?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Why? Objects on Earth are always accelerating too when they fall and do reach a terminal velocity. Only in a perfect vacuum getting ever closer to c is possible as far as I understand things.

Comment: @SV Yup, constant force, my bad

Comment: @SV smooth I guess

Comment: I did a small calculation, but I won't post it as an answer because it's not very helpful. Using the classical terminal velocity equation (viscosity hasn't been worked out in relativity yet) I get $V_t=\alpha\frac{\sqrt{F}}{R}$ where $\alpha$ can take values from $6.2\times10^7$ to $1.9\times10^{11}$ ($\text{m}^{3/2}\text{kg}^{-1/2}$). (I ignored the coronal gas in the range because you are not going to be traveling over stars). The formula only works out with moderate accuracy if $\frac{R}{\sqrt{N}}<1500 \text{m}/\text{N}^{1/2}$, otherwise relativistic effects give more than 10% error.

Comment: But if you think about it, a force of $4 \text{N}$ acting on a spaceship of $3 \text{km}$ in size is basically a joke.

Comment: Even at a minuscule ~10 km/s, the moving object would start to suffer from ablation due to impacting dust and radiation.  The rate of and drag due to ablation would only increase as the speed of the object increased (if it is a solid, "thick" object otherwise beyond some speed the dust would just ballistically pass through without transferring a lot of its momentum).

Comment: 2 equally sized orbs are traveling through space. They might be close or very far apart. They might be traveling towards each other or not. If there relative speed was close to light is there a signature?

Answer (score 1):

A way to calculate a "worst case" limit (ignoring for example the cosmic microwave background) would be to assume that every particle the vehicle hits is simply reflected.  We know that the average mass density $D$ of the intergalactic medium is something less than $10^{-27} kg/m3$.  Classically, a vehicle with cross sectional area of $A$, moving at a speed of $V$ relative to that medium would result in a "frictional" force of $2 A V D$.  Terminal velocity $V_t$ would be the velocity $V$ at which the accelerating force $F$ is equal to the frictional force: $$F = 2AVD$$ or terminal velocity $$V_t = F/(2AD)$$

If the force is large and the cross section is small, then relativistic effects can come into play, requiring a correction term which will make D effectively larger (thus increasing the effective $F$ and will also add a velocity-dependent term to $2AVD$ which further increases the effective $F$.

Answer (score 0):

The air resistance formula says that the resistance is proportional to the density of the medium and the square of the velocity. The density of the interstellar medium varies, but let us assume it is 10<sup>-16</sup> the density of air. That would suggest that the terminal velocity might be 10<sup>8</sup> times the terminal velocity of an object falling through air, assuming the force were comparable to 1g, which would mean that c might be the limiting factor rather than the resistance due to the medium.